# Adaptation of segregation model: how to avoid other breed densities at patch-here

Tags: netlogo, agent

The objective of my submodel is to simulate wolves avoiding patches that have a human density greater than their tolerance threshold. The human agents are created only on the urban-patches (grey), but there are grass-patches (brown) and forest-patches (green) in the NetLogo world as well (See interface tab link below for visual). The human agents are stationary whereas the wolf agents have the option to flee and [find-new-spot] if they are [not happy?] with their current location.

[Interface Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVqRK.png)

```
globals [
  grass-patches
  forest-patches
  urban-patches
  percent-unhappy
  ]

breed [wolves wolf]

breed [humans human]

wolves-own [
  happy?
  anthro_tolerance
  ]

humans-own [
  human-population]

patches-own [
  human-density]


;; creating the urban patches
  set urban-patches patches with [pxcor < 10 and pycor < -30 ]
  ask urban-patches [set pcolor grey]
  ask urban-patches [set human-density human-density = pop-density]


to-report pop-density
      report count humans / (count urban-patches)
    end
```

The code for the wolves to determine their happy? level and report the %-unhappy is:

```
to update-wolves
  ask wolves [
    set anthro_tolerance 0.049
    ifelse (patch-here human-density >= anthro_tolerance)  ;;Error message
    [set happy? FALSE]
    [set happy? TRUE]
  ]
end

to update-globals
  set percent-unhappy (count wolves with [not happy?]) / (count wolves) * 100
end
```

How do I code the ifelse happy? to represent the individual wolf asking itself "what is the human-density of the patch I'm on, and is it above my anthro_tolerance?"

Also, when I inspect a patch, the human-density variable is zero for all urban patches (even if there is a human on the patch). How can I correct this?

Comment: Please edit your question. Since the problem is that the code for checking happiness is not working, that is the code we need. You need to copy it in to the question (you can use the curly braces to format it as code). Images of code are not acceptable on StackOverflow. If we need to edit your code to make it work, we can't do that from an image.

Comment: @JenB, thank you for the guidance in StackOverflow. I appreciate your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I can see a couple of problems here. The first is:

```
ask urban-patches [set human-density human-density = pop-density]
```

I'm not sure why that's not throwing an error. But anyway, you don't use '=' to `set` variable values in NetLogo. Assuming your intent is that you want to assign the calculated value of pop-density to the patch variable named human-density, that line should be:

```
ask urban-patches [set human-density pop-density]
```

On to your actual error. You have:

```
ifelse (patch-here human-density >= anthro_tolerance)
```

The correct syntax for retrieving the value of a variable belonging to some model entity uses the primitive `of`, so you could write (not tested):

```
ifelse ([human-density] of patch-here >= anthro_tolerance)
```

But you can also take advantage of that fact that turtles have access to the patch variables of the patch where they are located. Note that this doesn't work in reverse - turtle to patch is unique because a turtle can only be in one place at a time. However, there can be many turtles on the one patch, so a patch wouldn't know which turtle to access the variable of.

Using that trick gets you to:

```
ifelse human-density >= anthro_tolerance
```

There's another trick that you can use because your `ifelse` is setting a variable to true of false. This is a bit subtle so some people don't use it as it's a little harder to read, particularly if you are newish to NetLogo. But you can replace:

```
ifelse human-density >= anthro_tolerance
[set happy? FALSE]
[set happy? TRUE]
```

with:

```
set happy? human-density < anthro_tolerance
```

Read this from right to left. First it applies the comparison operator '<' and reports `true` if `human-density < anthro_tolerance` or `false` if not `human-density < anthro_tolerance`. That value (`true` or `false`) is then given to the variable named "happy?".

Comment: `set human-density human-density = pop-density` doesn't throw an error because it's legal code — `human-density = pop-density` reports `true` or `false`, and `set` then stores that value in `human-density`.

Comment: Thank you, @JenB! Your explanations really help me conceptualize the code and syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I answered the last part of my question on my own, but I wanted to post how I resolved the issue if anyone is curious or new to NetLogo like myself..

When I inspected an individual urban-patch, the patch's variable "human-density" would be 0 even if there was a human agent (very clearly) on the patch. I worked this kink out by adding an [update-patches] at the end of my [setup] and [go] procedure.

```
to update-patches
  ask urban-patches [set human-density pop-density]
end
```

By having this update-patches command called at the end of the [setup] and [go] procedures, the human-density was accurately shown when I inspected a patch.